# Scrollview and graph zooming with agraphengine

Tags: android, graph, scrollview, zooming

I got an activity formed by a ScrollView that contains several Relative and LinearLayouts.
In particular I got a RelativeLayout which contains 2 LinearLayouts with 2 Line-Graphs inside,made using AChartEngine.

[image: example]

(The graphs are drawn in the gray boxes using a switch)
Here's the problem:I enabled zooming and pan on the graphs in this way:

```
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true,true);
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, true);
```

Anyway,when I zoom in/out the graphs,I am unable to move them vertically because this triggers the scrollview and the activity scrolls up/down,preventing me from moving my graphs in that direction,while the horizontal movement of the graphs works fine.
I need something that could stop the scrollview when the graph is being zoomed in/out or moved,I think.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

did you tried using the addOnItemTouchListener and inside the 
onInterceptTouchEvent

use this code

```
int action = e.getAction();
switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    break;
}
```

Comment: could you be more specific?
Do I have to add the onTouchListener on the boxes that contain the graphs?